# MySQL get Top 3 scores and give them different reward

Tags: php, mysql

I got problem.

```
    <?php
    include "base.php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Score > 0 ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $name = $row['Name'];
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

As you can see, using above code I can print out top 3 persons' names.
and if I add this into the loop:

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + $reward WHERE Name = '$name'");
```

they will get same reward.

So I think I need to get their names to give them different rewards.

```
    $reward1 = 1000;
    $reward2 = 500;
    $reward3 = 100;
```

How can I get their names? or is there any way to do this job?

Comment: do you want, update `$reward1` to first record and `$reward2` to second and further respectively ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to, Instead of variables, you can create an array of rewards, and call it in while loop respectively, see example below :

```
$rewards = array(
    1000,
    500,
    100
);

$rewardIndex = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Balance = Balance + $rewards[$rewardIndex] WHERE Name = '$name'");
    $rewardIndex++;
}
```

Note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in future, You can instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: As a note:  although this works, it requires executing multiple queries to the database.  Doing all the work using a single query is normally more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate them using variables and then use this in a `case` statement.  In fact, you can do the whole thing in SQL:

```
UPDATE users u
    SET balance = (CASE @rn := COALESCE(@rn + 1, 1)
                        WHEN 1 THEN balance + 1000
                        WHEN 2 THEN balance + 500
                        WHEN 3 THEN balance + 100
                        ELSE balance
                 END)
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 3;
```

EDIT:

The user defined variable just saves an extra `join`:

```
UPDATE users u JOIN
       (SELECT u2.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
        FROM users u2 CROSS JOIN
             (SELECT @rn := 0) params
        ORDER BY score DESC
        LIMIT 3
       ) u2
       ON u.user_id = u2.user_id
    SET u.balance = (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN balance + 1000
                          WHEN rn = 2 THEN balance + 500
                          WHEN rn = 3 THEN balance + 100
                          ELSE balance
                     END);
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't let you initialize variables in the `update` statement, when you are using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The user-defined variable `@rn` persists for the session; if it's already set in the session, it needs to be re-initialized before this statement. MySQL Reference manual warns against using user-defined variables in a context like this; but we do observe repeatable behavior.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . You can see the edit to my answer.  That construct is most useful when it may not be possible to execute multiple statements at one time.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't permit `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` with `ORDER BY`, so you cannot initialize the variable in the same statement when you need the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes, that works.  A separate `SET @rn := 0;` statement immediately before the update would also work. (Personally I prefer doing the initialization in the statement, like you've shown in your edit.)